# Uk Spouse Visa/Dependant

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, dependent-visa, uk-visa

I am married to a British national and would like to apply for a spouse visa for me and my daughter ( my husband is not the father) the child's birth certificate does not have fathers name. I am take sole care of the child.

My question is do i need a letter from the father to consent her travelling? Apart from Birth certificate and passport what other documents do I need?

Note we meet the other requirements

We are Kenyans and I don't have any legal documents saying I have sole responsibility. I practically live with her and I make all decisions in regards to her.

Comment: What is your and your daughter's citizenships?

Comment: Do you have a document showing that you have sole legal responsibility for your daughter?  If so, I suppose you don't need her father's permission.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify questions, putting on hold.